# Fasten python dataframe vectorialisation

Tags: performance, numpy, dataframe, vectorization

I have the below dummy dataframe:

```
import pandas
tab_size = 300000

tab_de_merde = [[i*1, 0, i*3, [i*7%3, i*11%3] ] for i in range(tab_size)]
colnames = ['Id', "Date", "Account","Value"]
indexnames = ['Id']
df = pandas.DataFrame(tab_de_merde, columns = colnames ).set_index(indexnames)
```

And I want to check if the column "Value" contains a 0.
I've tried 3 different solution and I was wondering if the third one (Python Vectorization) was correctly implemented since it doesn't seem to fasten the whole code.

```
%timeit  df[[(0 in x) for x in df['Value'].values]]
#108 ms ± 418 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


%timeit df[df['Value'].apply(lambda x: 0 in x)]
#86.2 ms ± 649 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

def list_contains_element(np_array): return [(0 in x) for x in np_array]
%timeit df[list_contains_element(df['Value'].values)]
#106 ms ± 807 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

I would be very glad if someone could help me understand better how to be faster with vector manipulation.

Comment: With nested list, looping is probably the best option.

Comment: I think it would be possible to unpack the nested list, use the numpy in1d function, then repack the list, the exact same way, and it the length of each individual list can change...so can't use zip here.

Comment: There is `pd.Series.explode()` option to unpack the lists, but the overhead for memory allocation is just too much.

Comment: yep, seems like it cannot be fastened then.